# Subquery in pl/pgsql is not worked

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have function in pl/pgsql in postgresql

ie

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION check_checklist_is_finalizedtest(application_id bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
sqlresult record;
val boolean:=false;

BEGIN

for sqlresult in execute IMMEDIATE 'select distinct mda.application_id maid,mda.document_type_id mdoctypeid,
dt.multiple_doc dtmdoc,mda.mandatory_doc_application_id mdocaid,COALESCE(ac.doc_correct,false) doccorrect,
COALESCE((select max(e_certificate_no) from application_document ad
 where ad.application_id=mda.application_id and ad.document_id=mda.document_type_id and multiple_doc=true and ad."valid"=''||New||''
 ),'''||1||''')as no_of_docs,
(select count(*) from application_document ad2 
 where ad2.application_id=mda.application_id and ad2.document_id=mda.document_type_id and ad2."valid"=''||New||''
 )as count_of_record     
from mandatory_doc_application mda 
inner join document_type dt on(mda.document_type_id=dt.document_id)
left  join application_checklist ac on(ac.man_doc_app_id= mda.mandatory_doc_application_id)
where mda.application_id='''||$1||''''
LOOP     
 IF(sqlresult.no_of_docs::bigint=sqlresult.count_of_record and sqlresult.doccorrect=true) then
   val=true;
 ELSE
   val=false;
 END IF;
 return next sqlresult;
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

When function is called subqueries in select statement are not executed.Hence the result is wrong.Can you help me?

Comment: Don't unload your mess into this forum. Present your code in a readable fashion and add at least rudimentary explanation what you are doing. Add your version of Postgres and describe what's wrong (which "subqueries" are not executed?).

Answer (score 1):

Probably something went wrong translating your query to dynamic SQL. The code in your question is very hard to read, which increases the risk of errors.
This strange expression probably does not what you think it does:

```
and ad2."valid"=''||New||''
```

You expect a variable *New*, but it is not declared and you use a constant string there instead.

Next strange thing: the key word `IMMEDIATE` - PostgreSQL doesn't support it - so your code cannot be compiled probably.

Questions:

- Why do you use a dynamic SQL? There doesn't seem to be need for that.
- *If* you use a dynamic SQL, why you don't use a modern form like

  ```
  FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM tab WHERE somecol = $1' USING $1
  LOOP ...
  ```

But your code would be simpler and faster with plain SQL:

```
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT no_of_docs::bigint=count_of_record 
                  AND COALESCE(ac.doc_correct,false) = true
                 FROM ...;
  RETURN;
END;
```

Remember to only select columns that you actually need to return - not others.

Comment: Sir 'New' is not a varaible,it is a constant string.And I have removed "IMMEDIATE".But the same result

Comment: Then, why you use a string concat operator? When "New" is constant, then you don't need it concat dynamically